# Entity Framework: partially update record not working

Tags: entity-framework, repository, unit-of-work

I have the following set up:

[image]
All instances are injected, UnitOfWork and DataContext are singletons.

I want to do a partial update of a record. 
In the generic repository, I have the following code in my update statement:

```
dbSet.Attach(entity);
if (updatedProperties != null)
{
   foreach (var property in updatedProperties)
   {
      unitOfWork.DataContext.Entry<TEntity>(entity).Property(property).IsModified = true;
   }
}
```

In my update method, I accept a List of string with the updated fields.

This method is called from the usermanager with the following code:

```
userRepo.Update(origUser, updatedProperties);
if(processToDB)
{
    unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
}
```

The variable *processToDB* is set to true. I step into the code, I see in the changetracker that the entity is there, but the update never happens.

So, what fixes this for me, but I don't find this a good fix, is calling the *SaveChanges* method directly from the Update method in the generic repository:

```
dbSet.Attach(entity);
if (updatedProperties != null)
{
   foreach (var property in updatedProperties)
   {
      unitOfWork.DataContext.Entry<TEntity>(entity).Property(property).IsModified = true;
   }
   unitOfWork.SaveChanges(); //added
}
```

Why doesn't it work when calling the savechanges on the user manager, it is after all the samen unitOfWork and DataContext (because they are singletons).

Comment: *"I step into the code, I see in the changetracker that the entity is there..."* Is the state of the entity `Modified`?

Comment: Unchanged, but in the second case (directly calling the SaveChanges method) Modified. But when I set it to Modified after I have set the properties, it will update the whole record.

Comment: No, it should be set automatically when you mark some of the properties as `Modified`. If the state is `Unchanged`, something wrong is going on there. In the second case, instead of calling `SaveChanges` (you shouldn't do that anyway), is the state `Modified` (`unitOfWork.DataContext(entity).State`)? And right after the call to `userRepo.Update`, the `unitOfWork.DataContext(origUser).State`. If they are different, the `DbContext`s must be different. Or some multithreading (`Attach` will reset the state to `Unchanged`)

Comment: You are right, in code not copied here, I've set the state back to unchanged (some synchronization I had to do).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set `IsModified` for each entity properties. Use `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` property and set as `true` while initialize your EF model as

`DbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;`

It will make EF to track changes on your entity object. You may check it by using 
`unitOfWork.DataContext(entity).State == EntityState.Modifed`.

If the above condition get paced then update your entity.